# quadratic formula using python

Tags: python

Trying to create a program that takes in three arguments that represent the a, b, and c values in the quadratic formula.  The values should be to two decimal places.  You do not need to account for imaginary values.  Then print out both roots in the form:

```
The solutions are x and y
```

Where `x` and `y` correspond to the positive and negative roots, respectively.

Having issues with my code:

```
import math

a = float(input('please input a number:'))
b = float(input('please input a number3:'))
c = float(input('please input a number2:'))
d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

sol1 = str(round((-b-cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a),2))
sol2 = str(round((-b+cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a),2))

print('The solution are {1.real:.2f} and {0.real:.2f}'.format(sol1,sol2))
```

Comment: You're forcing you results to string (`str(round(...))`) and then asking for the real parts of them when you print. They're no longer complex numbers; they're strings.

Comment: There's no need to call `str` or `round`. The `format` method will take care of converting the float to a string, and rounding the float to the requested number of decimal places in the process.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you imported math but used cmath. But, a simpler solution would be to not import anything and use the built in power function. Also, python handles printing integers, floats, and complex numbers by itself, so you don't need to worry about casting.

Try this:

```
# Get inputs
a = float(input("a: "))
b = float(input("b: "))
c = float(input("c: "))

# Calculate discriminant
discriminant = b**2 - 4*a*c

# Get solutions, x^0.5 = square root
x1 = (-b + discriminant**0.5) / (2*a)
x2 = (-b - discriminant**0.5) / (2*a)

# Output
print(f"Solutions: {x1} and {x2}")
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added an explanation now.

Comment: You are aware that `cmath` is more precise for dealing with complex numbers, aren't you? `cmath.sqrt(-1)` is `1j` while `(-1) ** 0.5` is `(6.123233995736766e-17+1j)`.